# display getelementsbyclassname value with dynamic list

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, getelementsbyclassname

I am new to jquery so i am learning as a go along,I have a dynamic list that has unique values.I am using the getelementsbyclassname to retrieve these values on button click.initially it would only display the first value in the list no matter which button i clicked so I added a for loop and now it display all the values on one click.I need it to display the value of that row each time the button is clicked.

```
       <li>cats
        <param class="lke" value="152">
      <button class="btnSave">Save Click</button>

        </li> 
      <li>dogs 
        <param class="lke" value="151">
      <button class="btnSave">Save Click</button>

        </li>
       <li>Fish
        <param class="lke" value="150">
      <button class="btnSave">Save Click</button>

        </li>


   $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".btnSave").click(
        function () {
            popUp();
        }            
    );
});



var arr =document.getElementsByClassName('lke');

 function popUp(){

for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
    alert(arr[i].value);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
// Bind to button click event
$('.btnSave').click(function(){
    // Alert the value attribute. This will always return for the first matching element
    alert($('.lke').attr('value'))
})
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/tk9kx8gz/

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for the response,I need the function to display the current value attribute,so how do i get it to display the next value e.g 151

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this script can help you

```js
$('button.btnSave').click(function () {
  var param = $(this).prev();
  var value = $(param).attr('value');
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>cats
        <param class="lke" value="152">
      <button class="btnSave">Save Click</button>

        </li> 
      <li>dogs 
        <param class="lke" value="151">
      <button class="btnSave">Save Click</button>

        </li>
       <li>Fish
        <param class="lke" value="150">
      <button class="btnSave">Save Click</button>

        </li>
```